# Performance on querying only the most recent entries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I made an app that saves when a worker arrives and departures from the premises.

Over a 24 hours multiple checks are made, so the database can quickly fill hundreds to thousands of records depending on the activity.

```
|   user_id | device_id | station_id |          arrived_at |         departed_at |
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        67 |        46 |          4 | 2020-01-03 11:32:45 | 2020-01-03 11:59:49 |
|       254 |       256 |          8 | 2020-01-02 16:29:12 | 2020-01-02 16:44:65 |
|        97 |        87 |          7 | 2020-01-01 09:55:01 | 2020-01-01 11:59:18 |
...
```

This becomes a problem since the daily report software, which later reports who was absent or who made extra hours, filters by arrival date.

The query becomes a full table sweep:

> (I just used SQLite for this example, but you get the idea)

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM activities
    WHERE user_id = 67
      AND arrived_at > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND departed_at < '2020-01-01 23:59:59'
ORDER BY arrived_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

What I want to make is **make the query snappier for records created (arrived) only the most recent day**, since queries for older days are rarely executed. Otherwise, I'll have to deal with timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following index, so that `departed_at` that don't match can be eliminated before probing the table:

```
CREATE INDEX ON activities (arrived_at, departed_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Postgres, you may use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
FROM activities
ORDER BY user_id, arrived_at::date DESC;
```

This assumes that you only want to report the latest record, as determined by the arrival date, for each user.  If instead you just want to show all records with the latest arrival date across the entire table, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE arrived_at::date = (SELECT MAX(arrived_at::date) FROM activities);
```

Comment: The problem is avoiding going for the entire table for all the records. If that the case, it's only a matter of time that queries become slow.

Comment: You can't "avoid" the entire table.  The closest thing to what you have in mind would be to use an index.  For the first query, the entire table must be considered as there is no `WHERE` clause.